Unable to access link to scrap data using Selenium
I am newbie in using Selenium. Recently, I am trying to scrap data from JODI data source. This link is workable in browser but when I use Selenium or bs4 to access this link (in code) it shows error (unable to access). If not mistaken, this is a dynamic website
Error Screenshot
I have installed chrome driver and this is the first few lines of my code. Any idea how to solve this?
import time
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)

driver.get(r'http://www.jodidb.org/TableViewer/tableView.aspx')


The problem is you are missing the rest of the URL that specifies a report.
Your URL
http://www.jodidb.org/TableViewer/tableView.aspx

A valid URL
http://www.jodidb.org/TableViewer/tableView.aspx?ReportId=93906
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Pick the desired report, copy the full URL, and then it should work.

Oh thanks! That's why i feel weird because previously when I am working on those APIs, there will be endpoint like what you mentioned above. But for this link, it has the report id at the main page but once i filter it (only want certain years and product) then the link will only omit the reportID
